# NotesSQL - ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 126

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using windows 10. I successfully installed NotesSQL 9.0 but unable to add ODBC driver and getting the such a error:

`The setup routines for the Lotus Notes SQL driver (*.nsf) ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 126: The specified module could not be found. (C:\NotesSQL\nsqlc32.dll).`

I checked the .dll and it is existing in the path that it showed. I did many different way of fixing this issues but could not fix it. Please anyone help to advise? Thank you.

Comment: not sure for version 9, but for NotesSQL ver 8.5.3, you need to append  your notes.ini , nnotes.dll and notessql folder path into Environment PATH variable

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added your `notes.ini` file to the PATH variable. This file is required by ODBC driver to run. By default your notes.ini should be in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.ini`

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot hours trying to find out a solution, I discovered one that solves to me: add the path of your **Notes client** at your path environment (user and system path) and it will work fine! Tell us if its solves for you.